# How to make a bit false when user select checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

Hi coder i have a search user page where i have a texbox, button and a gridview. Now when i enter name of the user and click on search button i get the detail of the user.

My database is like this

[image]

I already bind my gridview on page load so that i can also view the details of user in gridview like this:

[image]

Now in this gridview you can see a IsEnable header which have checkbox control. That Enable is a bit which is always true when user is created.

What i want is when user click on that checkbox that bit become false i try this on the rowdatabound but it give me object reference error can you guys tell me what i do to make my bit false when user select that checkbox

Please help me on this thanks in advance

Now this what i done now with my code now tell me how to update my enable bit from true to false on row update

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.GetGridData();
    }
}
protected void BindGrid()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CreateUser", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    } 
}
private void GetGridData()
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "Select * from CreateUser";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
protected void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
}
protected void lnkdelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    //getting particular row linkbutton
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    //getting userid of particular row
    int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    string FirstName = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from CreateUser where UserID=" + UserID, con);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        BindGrid();
        //Displaying alert message after successfully deletion of user
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('" + FirstName + " details deleted successfully')", true);
        this.GetGridData();
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    //{
    //    //getting username from particular row
    //    string FirstName = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "FirstName"));
    //    //identifying the control in gridview
    //    LinkButton lnkbtnresult = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkdelete");
    //    //raising javascript confirmationbox whenver user clicks on link button
    //    lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + FirstName + "')");
    //}
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GetGridData();
}
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label userid= (Label)row.FindControl("lblUserID");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete FROM CreateUser where UserID='" + Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()) + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    BindGrid();
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    string userid = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserID"].ToString();
    //Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblUserID") as Label;
    TextBox FirstName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
    TextBox LastName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;
    TextBox DomainID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDomainID") as TextBox;
    TextBox EmailID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmailID") as TextBox;
    TextBox Password = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPassword") as TextBox;
    TextBox ConfirmPassword = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtConfirmPassword") as TextBox;
    TextBox RoleType = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRoleType") as TextBox;
    CheckBox IsEnable = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkIsEnableEdit") as CheckBox;
    //TextBox textadd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadd");
    //TextBox textc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtc");
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    con.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail", conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update CreateUser set FirstName='" + FirstName.Text + "',LastName='" + LastName.Text + "',DomainID='" + DomainID.Text + "',EmailID='" + EmailID.Text + "',Password='" + Password.Text + "',ConfirmPassword='" + ConfirmPassword.Text + "',RoleType='" + RoleType.Text + "',Enable='" + IsEnable.Checked + "' where UserID='" + userid + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    BindGrid();
    //GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();
}
```

}

Comment: What line is the object reference error on?  BTW, `if (chk.Checked && chk==null)` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: sry i didnt update that its only if(chk.checked) not if(chk.checked && chk==null)

Comment: Why are you going over the grid's raws, but then check  e.Row?

Comment: i just gave you a example i know i am wrong thats why i ask an ques here mate

Comment: So.. what is the question?  The code and your comments don't jive.  Can you edit the question to show what's going on?  In other words are you still getting the object ref error or not?  The part about "i know i am wrong" is odd.  What part do you know is wrong?  I'm really confused.

Comment: i edit my question now i have now rowdatabound command can you guys guide me how to proceed

Comment: why do it on `RowDataBound` event ?

Comment: @SurajSingh i am asking best suitable solution from you guys.  You can give me other solution also

Comment: done guys the code i gave to you make my bit from 1 to 0

Comment: Well i really do not have a clear idea what your requirement is but for fetching values @ RowDatabound refer to update answer .

Comment: my updated question is my answer i didn't check it before but its working fine now thanks a lot for your response Suraj

Comment: I do not get it ? you are not doing anything @ `RowDataBound` event .

Comment: i got my answer mate let me post my answer here wait

Answer (score 1):

Put some defensive coding in first, and find out where the object reference error is happening:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
     if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        var chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEnable");
        if (chk == null || !chk.checked) return; 
        var userId  =GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) return;
        var query = "update CreateUser set Enable='False' where UserID='" + userid + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
      }
}
```

You can use the CheckChanged event:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnable" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="ChkEnable_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And then update the database in CheckChanged event:

```
protected void ChkEnable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
  var userId = gridView.DataKeys[selRowIndex].Value as string;
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId)) return;
  var checkBox = gridView.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("chkEnable") as CheckBox;
  if (checkBox == null) return;
  var query = "update CreateUser set Enable= @Enabled where UserID='" + userid + "'";
  cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Enabled", checkBox.Checked);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();

}
```

Comment: your code is ok but when i check the checkbox i want to make that enable bit to false which is not doing well

Comment: how can click event of checkbox work if i click on the checkbox then my update query fire and changes into the database

Comment: Is Enable column bool in the database? Or is it a string which stores "false"? if it is bool, then you can set Enable=0

Comment: it is bool in database can you explain me how to make it 0 on checkbox click event or on rowdatabound when user click on check box

Comment: As far as I am aware, row databound is fired when the row is bound, and not on user interaction. You can use the checkchanged event.

Comment: there is no click event on OnCheckchange ingridview check box

Comment: click = checkchanged. When you click on checkbox, it changes the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you doing it on `RowDataBound` event ? RowDataBound occurs when a row is 
  bounded to gridview but here we have to update gridview rows.
  If you have to update your rows you can do it on `RowUpdating` command .

```
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
       {       

           Checkbox chkbx = ((Checkbox)(row.Cells[8].Controls[0]));
           bool IsChecked =chkbx.Checked ;           
           //You can write your update command here.
       }



 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
     {
          GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

           TextBox MyName= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("FirstName");

           string name = Myname.text; 
          //For checkbox
           Checkbox chkbx = (Checkbox)e.Row.FindControl("IsEnabled");

           if(chkbx.Checked ==true) 
            {
                // do your stuff for checkbox checked.
            }
           else
             {
                // do your stuff if checkbox is not selected
              }
           }
    }
```

Comment: i have to check which id is selected using row data bound so that i can make changes in database

Comment: how can click event of checkbox work if i click on the checkbox then my update query fire and changes into the database

Comment: See it's a bad idea to change database values for each click on `checkbox` i would suggest you to create a button or something that can update rows which you have `checked` or `unchecked`.

Comment: `RowDataBound` event will come when you are giving a datasource to your gridview ,So that means your gridview is getting populated from `database` itself so if you want to check which id is selected you can but for what purpose ? Your data is already coming from `database` so what to update on database?

Comment: See you will not get those checked values which you checked on `UI` on `RowDatabound` event untill and unless you have saved your changes i database .

Comment: Now guys i made some change with my question see my updated question and reply according to it

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got my answer thanks for your reply guys

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    this.GetGridData();
}
}
 protected void BindGrid()
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CreateUser", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
    GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
    GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
    GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
} 
}
  private void GetGridData()
  {
   con.Open();
   string query = "Select * from CreateUser";
   da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   GridView1.DataSource = ds;
   GridView1.DataBind();
   con.Close();
  }
protected void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
}
protected void lnkdelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    //getting particular row linkbutton
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    //getting userid of particular row
    int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    string FirstName = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from CreateUser where UserID=" + UserID, con);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result == 1)
   {
       BindGrid();
       //Displaying alert message after successfully deletion of user
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('" + FirstName + " details deleted successfully')", true);
       this.GetGridData();
   }
}


protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
GetGridData();
}
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label userid= (Label)row.FindControl("lblUserID");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete FROM CreateUser where UserID='" + Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()) + "'", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
BindGrid();
}
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
string query = string.Empty;
string userid = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserID"].ToString();
//Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblUserID") as Label;
TextBox FirstName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
TextBox LastName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;
TextBox DomainID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDomainID") as TextBox;
TextBox EmailID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmailID") as TextBox;
TextBox Password = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPassword") as TextBox;
TextBox ConfirmPassword = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtConfirmPassword") as TextBox;
TextBox RoleType = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRoleType") as TextBox;
CheckBox IsEnable = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkIsEnableEdit") as CheckBox;
//TextBox textadd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadd");
//TextBox textc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtc");
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
con.Open();
//SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail", conn);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update CreateUser set FirstName='" + FirstName.Text + "',LastName='" + LastName.Text + "',DomainID='" + DomainID.Text + "',EmailID='" + EmailID.Text + "',Password='" + Password.Text + "',ConfirmPassword='" + ConfirmPassword.Text + "',RoleType='" + RoleType.Text + "',Enable='" + IsEnable.Checked + "' where UserID='" + userid + "'", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
BindGrid();
//GridView1.DataBind();
}
 protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
BindGrid();
}
}
```

Comment: ok so your are doing this in `GridView1_RowUpdating1` command thats what i was asking, because you were asking about `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: One more thing use parameterized query, Your query is prone to `SqlInjection`. One more thing, are you updating one row at a time, then you can do it using `RowCommand` event much easier.